# How can I download dynamically generated PDF files on PWA when added to home screen on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, progressive-web-apps

I have this PWA which the user can click on a link to generate a report in PDF format.
When the file opens I just have an OK button that close the file, nothing more, this behavior happens when user add it to the home screen:

https://i.redd.it/24rbih326q931.jpg

Tried an simple `<a href>` HTML tag, but in this case not even the ok to close the file is showing forcing me to restart the app.
When used JavaScript `function window.open()`, I had the option "Ok" which closes the file.

```html
<img src="pdf.png" onclick='geraPDF(1045, 45)'>
```

```js
function geraPDF(c, v){var jan=window.open("geraPdfTermoAdesao.php?c="+c+"&v="+v, "adesao", "location: 0;");}
```

I want to give the users options to print, share or even save locally that PDF file.
When the same app is used on a Safari Tab, I have those options disponible.

**EDIT 16/07/2019**
Looks like Safari is finally getting over the bug on tag: `<a href="" download="name">` as seen on: [iOS: Add support for the download attribute](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167341) this will finally get the download tag to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "install" a PWA on the home screen it renders according to the values chosen in the `display` property of the web app manifest (you can read more details [here](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa)), but other than that it is 1:1 as a *normal* web application.

Therefore if you want to provide HTML elements to interact with the page (if I understood your question rightly), you have to implement them by yourself. Eventually you can implement a custom menu or header bar.

---

**Update**

In general, if you plan to open external link within a PWA, for a better user experience those should be opened in the browser and not your PWA. Typically the user wants to remain in the PWA context.
Moreover if you open the PDF in a separate page, that is not inside or part of you app, then you cannot have extra buttons, other than the default ones provided by default by the browser.

What I would suggest to do is to try to open the PDF inside a div/container in your application (there are probably different libraries allowing it) and then add any UI element you might need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
On this specific case I can't provide HTML elements, because the PDF is open in a different window with no options at all.

Comment: See my updated answer. I hope I cold give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks Again for the answer, I'm working on this approach right now, tring to implement PDF.js.

Comment: Happy to know that. If my answer helped you, you can accept it and close the question.

Comment: Looks like Safari is finally getting over the bug on tag: <a href="" download="name"> as seen on: [iOS: Add support for the download attribute](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167341) this will finally get the download tag to work again.

Answer (score 1):

Working for me!

```js
    function downloadPDF(url) { 
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          var myBlob = this.response;
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
          link.download = "yourname.pdf";
          link.click();
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    }
```